Why is second inversion of a C major not a different chord?
Let's consider a C major triad: C-E-G. Its second inversion would be G-C-E. Why is this considered an inversion of C major, instead of Gsus4add6?

Do you mean in cadences (e.g. G64 -> G -> C), or any inversions in general?

It is -- all chords have multiple names.

See this answer to a question about identifying a chord solely by its notes. TLDR, you don't; you identify it by figuring out what it does in its context.

@AndyBonner Thanks that is essentially the answer I was looking for.

Adding to @AndyBonner's comment: the potential ambiguity you see can be "a feature, not a bug", depending on circumstances. :)

@Primordial_Hamster Looking at the "G-C-E" in the question and the notion of a suspension, I'm reminded of a seasonal example: In "O Come All Ye Faithful," if we're in C, the final line "Chri-ist the Lord" is often harmonized GCE resolving to GBD, then the tonic.

Under certain circumstances G-C-E can be interpreted as Gsus4add6 (or, Gsus4sus6).
The idea that C-E-G, E-G-C, and G-C-E are "the same chord" — when they are clearly different from each other in sound — is a core idea in the theory of (Tonal) music. It stems from the fact that when composers use those three pitches together, they tend to operate in the same way. That is, C-E-G will frequently move to C-F-A; E-G-C to F-A-C; and G-C-E to A-C-F. Alternatively, C-E-G might move to B-D-G; E-G-C to D-G-B; and G-C-E to G-B-D. This commonality of purpose gives rise to the idea of thinking of the various inversions of C-E-G as being variations on the "same chord".
On interesting exception is the "cadential 6-4" chord. In this case, when in the key of C major, G-C-E (a 6-4 chord) moves to G-B-D and then to C major. This raises the question of whether G-C-E is a C chord in second inversion or a G chord with two suspensions that then resolve into a normal G major triad.
In the key of C, a C chord (G-C-E) at a cadence should sound more or less resolved, but this chord doesn't; rather, it sounds more like it "resolves" to G, and it will tend to be preceded by, say, and A minor chord, with the C and E then being suspended into the following G chord — a situation relatively conventional at a cadence.
For this reason, some theorists categorize it as a C chord in second inversion, others as a G chord with suspensions, and others just call it "cadential 6-4", thus avoiding any need to debate whether its root is C or G.

"For this reason, some theorists categorize it as a C chord in second inversion, others as a G chord with suspensions" - I don't know, how it is considered in the Western musical theory, but in the Russian tradition there is no such thing as a "chord with suspensions". The suspension notes are considered as non-chord sounds left from the previous chord which makes a term "Gsus chord" meaningless. I know that this term exists in guitar practice, but it is a really bad and misleading thing to use such term as it confuses the musicians without solid theoretical training.

@user4035 "but in the Russian tradition there is no such thing as a "chord with suspensions". The suspension notes are considered as non-chord sounds left from the previous chord": but that's precisely what a suspension is.  That is like saying "there's no such thing as a wheel, there's only a disk rotating at the end of a pole that bears part of the weight of a vehicle and, by rotating, allows the vehicle to move horizontally."

Whichever order the three notes are played in, whether close or open harmony, the C tends to sound more like the root than the other two. Chords are generally titled using their root name as a starter. So it wouldn't make a lot of sense to call those three notes anything but a C something.
Calling it Gsus add4 is somewhat meaningless, as it's not a G based chord - G bassed, true, but not G based. PLus, why would it be advantageous to complicate the issue when C, 2nd inv. works perfectly well?

Sometimes it is.   I expect you're thinking of that common harmonic occurrence, the 'Cadential 6/4', where a second inversion I resolves to V.   Yes, it would make sense to consider this as a double suspension of a V chord, V(sus6)(sus4).   Not (add6) as the 6th replaces the 5th, it isn't an addition.   But the convention is to label it as V6/4.

Why not notate 2nd inversion C major as Gsus4add6?

Because Gsus4add6 would retain the D, which is not in the C major chord.
Because simpler name is better, especially when the "add6" is a much more important note (the 3rd of C) than the "add6" of most chords.
Because we notate a chord as "suspended" when in the next chord the "sus4" note would usually be resolved to the 3rd degree note of the same chord.  But in many places, a second inversion chord usually resolves to a different chord; see the cadential, passing, and pedal functions where it resolves to the related dominant (V) chord or the tonic (I) chord.  Even in the "Bass arpeggiation" type, the "sus 4" note stays the same in the next chord.

Why not consider a 2nd inversion a different chord?
Because in the context where 2nd inversion chord is used, the chord retains its harmonic function in the scale (see the above linked Wikipedia article).  The 2nd inversion form is used for smoother chord change, while a different chord is called for when the function changes.  Similarly, the "add6" is added in Jazz music to add a Jazzy feel without changing the harmonic function.
